# Embedded WLST minimal file set

Tags: java, weblogic, wlst

I'm using Eclipse to write a small Java application that uses WLST to manage a few development servers.  I want to be able to give this application to our developers who do not have Weblogic installed.  We are using Weblogic version 9.2.

When I add weblogic.jar to the classpath (but leave it in my WEBLOGIC_HOME tree) it works fine.  When I move the weblogic.jar to my projects /lib directory I get a failure when it tries to connect to node manager.

It is pretty clear that code in the weblogic jar is using hard coded relative paths to find other files.

Does anyone know the complete minimal set of files WLST needs to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. config.jar
2. jsafe.jar
3. jython.jar
4. pdev.jar
5. weblogic.jar
6. wlcipher.jar

   DemoTrust.jks needs to be on the class path.